# How to dynamically expose and view ActiveMQ Queues and Topics in New Relic

Tags: jvm, queue, activemq-classic, jmx, newrelic

I have an infra agent installed and am using JMX to get data into ActiveMQ.
My jvm-metrics.yml looks like this for my topic and queue entries, but I'm only able to enter two or three maximum and no others show up -

```
      - query: type=Broker,brokerName=<name>,destinationType=Topic,destinationName=<name> 
        attributes:
          - AlwaysRetroactive
          - AverageBlockedTime
          - AverageEnqueueTime
          - AverageMessageSize
          - BlockedSends
          - BlockedProducerWarningInterval
          - ConsumerCount
          - DequeueCount
          - DispatchCount
          - DLQ
          - EnqueueCount
          - ExpiredCount
          - ForwardCount
          - InFlightCount
          - MaxAuditDepth
          - MaxEnqueueTime
          - MaxMessageSize
          - MaxPageSize
          - MaxProducersToAudit
          - MemoryLimit
          - MemoryPercentUsage
          - MemoryUsageByteCount
          - MemoryUsagePortion
          - MinEnqueueTime
          - MinMessageSize
          - Name
          - Options
          - PrioritizedMessages
          - ProducerCount
          - ProducerFlowControl
          - QueueSize
          - SlowConsumerStrategy
          - StoreMessageSize
          - Subscriptions
          - TotalBlockedTime
          - useCache
```

I've tried using wildcards, but they aren't working for me. Is there another way to add the queues and topics? I'm also wanting to avoid having to gather a list of topics and queues manually.

Comment: What wildcards did you try? Did you get any errors when you tried them?

Comment: I tried these wildcards:
 - query: type=Broker,brokerName=*,destinationType=Topic,destinationName=* 
No errors as such but they weren't showing up in the dashboard